# SyntaxError when running some Python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea why I always have this error each time I tried to run some Python scripts. It's driving me nuts. I'm on Linux Mint and using Python3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/move_mouse_every_minute.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Xlib.protocol import display, request, event, rq
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 24, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/user/socket.py", line 6
    except socket.error, e: 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/email/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/user/socket.py", line 6
    except socket.error, e: 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/move_mouse_every_minute.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Xlib.protocol import display, request, event, rq
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 24, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/user/socket.py", line 6
    except socket.error, e: 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

The Python script requires **pyautogui** which I already installed using `pip3 install pyautogui`. Here's the code of the Python script I was trying to run:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
    for i in range(0,100):
        pyautogui.moveTo(1000,i*10)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Edit:

I tried again in a new Python3 virtual environment and still got the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../move_mouse_every_minute.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File ".../site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File ".../site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    from Xlib.display import Display
  File ".../site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Xlib.protocol import display, request, event, rq
  File ".../site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 24, in <module>
    import socket
  File ".../socket.py", line 6
    except socket.error, e: 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
```

Comment: You `import` `time` before using it; why don't you do the same with `pyautogui`?

Comment: `/home/user/socket.py`, is that your file? Why have you added your own home-directory to the Python module search path? And why have you added your directory *before* the standard Python directories?

Comment: your "socket.py" uses exception syntax looks like its intended for python3 -- syntax has changed

Comment: I think you meant `except socket.error as e:`

Comment: Don't give your own script the same name as standard modules. `import socket` is loading your own `socket.py` instead of using the standard socket module.

Comment: You didn't show the exact place the error occurs. `SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized` is because you did `except socket.error, e: ` instead of  `except socket.error as e`. So the interpreter sees socket.error and e as two exception types. This you didn't include in your code

Comment: @Barmar I'm confused. How is `import socket` is loading my `socket.py`? I do not have any personal socket script.

Comment: @journpy I do not know exactly where the error occurred. However, I do notice that this happens when trying to run many Python scripts. Could this be because `pip` installs modules in my home directory every time I run `pip3 install module-name`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, `import pyautogui` comes before `import time` within the code. I didn't realize It was omitted when copied and pasted. I'm not sure how my home directory was added to the Python module search path but it seems `pip` installs Python modules in my home directory instead of system-wide.

Comment: The error message comes from `/home/user/socket.py`. That's your personal socket script.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you. I didn't realize before I had a `socket.py` Python script in my home directory. Renaming it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Traceback you have a `socket.py` Python (personal) script (`File ".../socket.py", line 6` or `File "/home/user/socket.py", line 6`), it's not a build-in Python file. Your system finds that file and probably the Python wants to use your file instead of build-in socket module.

**Solution 1:**

The Exception handling is written in Python2 style in `socket.py` file but it's not compatible with Python 3 and this is the reason why the interpreter throws error for you. Python2/3 Exception reference: https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html

You should change that Exception handling:

From `except socket.error, e:` to `except socket.error as e:`

**Solution 2:**

You should rename the `/home/user/socket.py` file to something unique, then your system won't overwrite the build-in socket module. (Or you can remove the `socket.py` file if you are sure it's not used and not needed.)

I recommend the 2. solution because I am 98% sure if the Python uses that personal file instead of build-in socket module then your implementation won't be working after Exception fix, so in my opinion the renaming would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I didn't realize before I had `socket.py` in my home directory and thought this was coming from the default Python installation all along. I have no idea how I managed to put the Python file there. Renaming it solved the problem.